# The program doesn't reassign the value in my if else statment

Tags: java

I am very new to Java and my assignment was to make a tax calculator. Everything seems to be working fine but when I print at the end it always prints 0 for federaltaxes. I make the double at the start and then try to reassign it depending on the situation through the else if statement.

```
//2353161 Tomas Pospisil
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PaymentCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Create Scanner for user input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Ask the user for Gross Pay
        System.out.print("Please Enter Gross Pay: ");
        double GrossPay = input.nextInt();

        //Establish the integer for Number of Exemptions
        int NoE = 0;

        //Establish the integer for the value of exemption
        double exemptionvalue = 0;

        double federaltaxes = 0;

        //Ask the user if they are married
        System.out.print("Are you married: ");
        String marriedstatus = input.next();

        //If yes make the number of Exemptions equal the user input
        if (marriedstatus.equals("yes")) {
        System.out.print("Please enter Number of Exemptions: ");
            NoE = input.nextInt();
        }
        //If not make the number of exemptions equal 1
        else if(marriedstatus.equals("no")) {
         NoE = 1;
        }
        //If NoE is greater than 4 make it 5 for later use
        if (NoE >4) {
            NoE = 5;
        }

        // Depending on the number of exemptions the program assigns it a value for later use
        switch (NoE) {
        case 1: 
            exemptionvalue = 1000;
            break;
        case 2:
            exemptionvalue = 1800;
            break;
        case 3:
            exemptionvalue = 2400;
            break;
        case 4:
            exemptionvalue = 3600;
            break;
        case (5):
            exemptionvalue = 4000;
            break;  
        }

        //Calculate adjusted wages
        double adjustedwages = GrossPay - exemptionvalue;

        // Figure out the tax percentage
        if (GrossPay >= 10000) {
            federaltaxes = GrossPay * 0;
        }
        else if (GrossPay <= 30000 && GrossPay >= 10000) {
            federaltaxes = GrossPay * 0.15 ;
        }
        else if (GrossPay > 30000) {
            federaltaxes = GrossPay * 0.20 ;
        }


        //Program calculates the FICA
        double FICA = (GrossPay * .065);

        //Program calculates Medicare
        double Medicare = (GrossPay * .014);

        //Program calculates the federal taxes


        //Program Calculates Net Pay
        double NetPay = GrossPay - (FICA + Medicare + federaltaxes);    


        //Program prints the results
        System.out.println("   Payroll Taxes");
        System.out.println("Gross.....$ " + GrossPay);
        System.out.println("Exemptions:   " + NoE);
        System.out.println("Federal Taxes.....$ " + federaltaxes);
        System.out.println("   FICA.....$ " + FICA);
        System.out.println("   Medicare.....$ " + Medicare);
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
        System.out.println("Net Pay.....$ " + NetPay);







    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the block that is causing you trouble.

```
if (GrossPay >= 10000) {
        federaltaxes = GrossPay * 0;
    }
```

Any GrossPay amount above 10000 is going to pass the condition and be multiplied by 0.

Comment: Also, the code won't evaluate the rest of the 'else if' statements if the 'if' condition is passed. If you still want the 'else if' statements evaluated no matter what, turn them into plain 'if' statements.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong condition in the if where you evaluate federal taxes, it should be:

```
    if (GrossPay < 10000) {
        federaltaxes = GrossPay * 0;
    }
    else if (GrossPay <= 30000 && GrossPay >= 10000) {
        federaltaxes = GrossPay * 0.15 ;
    }
    else if (GrossPay > 30000) {
        federaltaxes = GrossPay * 0.20 ;
    }
```

your code will never evaluate the else condition

Answer (score 0):

It is because your condition logic is wrong

```
 double federaltaxes = 0;

// Figure out the tax percentage
if (GrossPay >= 10000) {
    federaltaxes = GrossPay * 0;
} else if (GrossPay <= 30000 && GrossPay >= 10000) {
    federaltaxes = GrossPay * 0.15;
} else if (GrossPay > 30000) {
    federaltaxes = GrossPay * 0.20;
}
```

Your first condition will always be true if the `Grosspay is >= 10000` so federaltaxes here is 0, then the rest of your if else will not be evaluated because your first condition will always evaluate first. Also you dont have a separate `else` statement for the rest of the scenarios